# What are all the recommended optimization techniques in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, bigdata

Well I know a few optimization techniques like Partition and Bucketing while writing a query . Running the hive in TEZ mode . But, other than that are there any other optimization techniques that are there in hive .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set atleast following parameters for performance optimization:-

`set set hive.exec.reducers.max=no_of_reducers;`  -- no of reducers for parallel processing.

`set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=value_in_bytes;` -- equally divide processing load to each reducer.

`set hive.auto.convert.join=true;` -- automatically converts the joins to mapjoins at runtime **if possible**,

`set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;`  -- if table is bucketed you need to write this parameter, no. of buckets will be equal to no. of reducers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many techniques:

- Using Tez
- Using ORCFile
- Using Vectorization
- Cost based query optimization
- Writing proper and efficient SQL

Please refer the below hortonworks post for more details:

http://hortonworks.com/blog/5-ways-make-hive-queries-run-faster/